# Gif is not playing after shared element transition. Glide v 4.8.0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-transitions

Gifs are playing in the list.
But after shared element transition it stops.

```
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
```

```
 GlideApp.with(this)
                .load(arguments?.getString(EXTRA_IMAGE_URL))
                .onlyRetrieveFromCache(true)
                .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                    override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                        startPostponedEnterTransition()
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                        startPostponedEnterTransition()
                        return false
                    }
                })
                .into(view.ivDialog)
```

Answer (score 1):

An ugly hack that works in my case (in Java sorry):

```
.listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
          return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
          if (resource instanceof GifDrawable){
            final Handler handler = new Handler();                
            handler.post(() -> resource.setVisible(true, true));
          }
          return false;
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

If **All** of your images are *Gifs* then simply add `.asGif` and replace your *listener* with `GifDrawable` like this,

```
GlideApp.with(this)
                .load(arguments?.getString(EXTRA_IMAGE_URL))
                .asGif()
                .onlyRetrieveFromCache(true)
                .listener(object : RequestListener<GifDrawable> {
                    override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<GifDrawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                        startPostponedEnterTransition()
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: GifDrawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<GifDrawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                        startPostponedEnterTransition()
                        return false
                    }
                })
                .into(view.ivDialog)
```

In case your images are not only Gifs, **Please check the below 2 solutions carefully**

**Solution 1-**

Make sure your **Activity B** is a ***translucent*** activity by setting

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

in your `Activity's Theme` only and only If your **Activity A** is translucent otherwise make sure both of your activities are non-translucent or translucent.

**Update: June 2020**

**Solution 2-**

In your activity's `onCreate()` method call `postponeEnterTransition()` before setting your content and call the `startPostponedEnterTransition()` in the Glide's both `onLoadFailed()` and `onResourceReady()` callbacks,

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        postponeEnterTransition()

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

         GlideApp.with(context)
        .load(myImageUrl)
        .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
        .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(
                e: GlideException?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<Drawable>?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                setStartPostponedTransition(itemImage)
                return false
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(
                resource: Drawable?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<Drawable>?,
                dataSource: DataSource?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                setStartPostponedTransition(itemImage)
                return false
            }

        })
        .into(itemImage)

}
```

Note, that this `setStartPostponedTransition()` is helper function and we are calling `startPostponedEnterTransition()` inside the `onPreDraw()` callback of your ImageView.

```
 private fun setStartPostponedTransition(image: ImageView) {
        image.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
            override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                image.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                startPostponedEnterTransition()
                return true
            }
        })
    }
```

Now your Gif's will play in your **ActivityB** while transitioning from **ActivityA** once your ImageView's layout gets drawn on the screen.

This solution is a crazy hack! I hope it will help.

Go with Solution 2 and you're ready to go!

Comment: This is not working in my case. And what happen if only a few images are Gifs?

Comment: @YiyoCastillo I've updated the answer, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue from the library and we will have to live with our custom own fixes. In my case, without causing any hindrance to the user, I reloaded the gif with a time delay so that it works seamlessly. (Anyways the image will be cached for the first time and Glide handles the subsequent calls efficiently)

```
imageView.loadImageIfAvailable(logoUrl)
imageView.transitionName = imageTransitionName
                handler = Handler()
                runnable = Runnable {
                    imageView.loadImageIfAvailable(logoUrl)
                } 
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000)
```

loadImageIfAvailable is my own extension function to load the image using Glide.

```
fun ImageView.loadImageIfAvailable(url: String?) {
    url?.let {
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .into(this)
    }
}


Note: Don't forget to unregister the handlers by calling removeCallbacks on onStop()
```

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    handler?.removeCallbacks(runnable)
}
```